# Error "no suitable method found" when sorting List in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I am trying to sort a `List` of `Integer`'s after converting a `List` of `String`'s into an `Integer` `List`. It gives me this error:

> no suitable method found for sort(List,StringToInteger.CustomComparator)

Here is my code:

```
public class StringToInteger {

    public static void main(String args) {
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        strList.add("34");
        strList.add("14");
        strList.add("42");
        strList.add("24");

        List<String> resultList = getIntegerArray(strList);
        System.out.println("before sorting"+resultList);
        Collections.sort(resultList, new CustomComparator());
        System.out.println("after sorting"+resultList);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getIntegerArray(List<String> stringArray) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(String stringValue : stringArray) {
            try {
                //Convert String to Integer, and store it into integer array list.
                result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringValue));
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                Log.w("NumberFormat", "Parsing failed! " + stringValue + " can not be an integer");
            } 
        }       
        return result;
    }

    class CustomComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
            return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorting List using **Collections.sort(resultList, new CustomComparator());**, it is there in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing Lists of Integers in your `CustomComperator`, while you should be comparing Integers.
You can sort the List also with

```
Collections.sort(resultList);
```

or

```
Collections.reverse(resultList);
```

Comment: Log.w("NumberFormat", "Parsing failed! " + stringValue + " can not be an integer"); in this line, its show error like symbol not found. why is that so.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> resultList = getIntegerArray(strList);
```

change this line to

```
List<Integer> resultList = getIntegerArray(strList);
```

and this

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {
@Override
public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
    return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
}
}
```

to

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
@Override
public int compare(Integer>o1, Integer o2) {
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the `sort` method prototype !

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
```

Your code do that:

```
Collections.sort(resultList, new CustomComparator());
```

Which is:

```
Collections.sort(List<String>, Comparator<List<Integer>>);
```

- `getIntegerArray` returns a `List<Integer>`. Your compiler should warn you or throw an error.
- By the sort contract, it expect a `Comparator<? super String>`. A `Comparator<List<Integer>>` is **not** a `Comparator<? super String>`.

For the rest, the other answers complete my answer.